# How to get Split image (VR Effect) in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Looking to create some basic VR apps - How do I go about splitting an image 50 / 50 in landscape mode. Is it possible to split the AVFoundation camera 50/50 so I can have a split live feed (one side for each eye).

I have tried creating 2 camera sessions etc and placing them in separate views but it crashes. Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The VR effect is not just splitting the view field in half. There's lots of processes to apply, geometric deformations of the angles in the image, etc, to give the illusion of stereographic immersion. This question is way too broad for SO I'm afraid. :)

Comment: Hi Eric, do you have any suggestions for tutorials? Thanks